# Laravel eloquent orm query using orwhere clause

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have been using this query to retrieve data based on orWhere clause

```
$q->where('created', $date);
$q->where(function ($query) {
  $query->where('gender', 'Male')
        ->where('age', '>=', 18);
})->orWhere(function($query) {
  $query->where('gender', 'Female')
        ->where('age', '>=', 30);   
})->orWhere(function($query) {
  $query->where('gender', 'Orthodox')
        ->where('age', '>=', 35);
```

first orWhere clause is working perfectly, however 2nd isnt. It seems to be a scope issue, i.e something with ()

Comment: Post the full query and fix the braces.

Comment: you could dump the generated sql query and start from there..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group your conditions properly and it should be fine.

```
$q->where('created', $date);
$q->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Male')
            ->where('age', '>=', 18);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Female')
            ->where('age', '>=', 30);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Orthodox')
            ->where('age', '>=', 35);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional `where()` closure:

```
$q->where('created', $date);
$q->where(function ($q) {
     $q->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Male')
            ->where('age', '>=', 18);
     })->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Female')
            ->where('age', '>=', 30);   
     })->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->where('gender', 'Orthodox')
            ->where('age', '>=', 35);
     });
});
```